# Tablesorter: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tablesorter'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter, tablefilter

I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tablesorter' "

I've tried using different versions of jQuery and putting the script link higher in the list of scripts but I can't figure out why I'm still getting this error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="stylesheets/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/third_party_js/tablefilter/v2_4/filtergrid.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/third_party_js/jquery_tablesorter/jquery_tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/third_party_js/tablefilter/v2_4/tablefilter.js"></script>
```

...

```
<table class="tablesorter" id="mytable" cellspacing="6">
<thead>
  <tr class="tr-head">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Length</th>
    <th>Priority</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

and the rest of the table follows. The script I'm running at the bottom is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#mytable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} );
  }
);
```

As you can see, I'm using TableFilter as well, but I don't think that should interfere. What am I missing?

Comment: Look in the browser console, you'll likely find a 404 related to the tablesorter.js file. If not that, double-check the capitalization of the function used by that plug-in, as JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Sadly there is no 404 and I copied the function from the plugin site (http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Download). I also double-checked the capitalization.

Comment: Most likely there's another instance of jQuery being included on your page sometime after the tablesorter.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Would including the tablefilter.js cause problems?

Comment: @kevingduck: *"I copied the function from the plugin site"* I would look in the plugin file just to be sure the documentation isn't out of date, which happens a *lot*. *"Would including the tablefilter.js cause problems?"* It's unlikely, but why don't you find out? Should take five minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't enough information in the question for us to be able to help you, as [this does fundamentally work](http://jsbin.com/EFAtos/1).